# Which anime is this character from?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, anime

[image]

Which anime does this character come from?  What is the genre? I'm trying to find more anime so that I don't run out of ones to watch.

Comment: If you run into problems like this where you don't know what the image is from, just do a reverse image search. :)

Comment: That shirt cannot be buttoned.

Comment: @misharosnach - Imagine her embarrassment when she realises!

Comment: @Richard Especially considering how easily embarrassed anime girls tend to be.

Answer (score 10):

This is a character from the anime ***[Ore, Twintail ni Narimasu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3985216/)*** (sometimes titled ***Gonna be the Twin-Tails!!*** in English).  Developed by [Production IMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_IMS), it began airing in Japan on October 9, 2014.  I've seen it described as an example of the "magical girl genre".

The character in question is **Twoearle (Tuāru)**, aka **"Thouars"**, voiced by Japanese actress and singer [Maaya Uchida](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maaya_Uchida).

[image]

**Note:** From what I have read, I would say this anime is fairly NSFW.

Comment: I'm going to start spelling ‘twirl’ _twoearle_ too from now on, just because I can!

Answer (score 1):

[Twoearle](http://myanimelist.net/character/111381/Twoearle) from Ore, Twintail Ni Narimasu.